# How to dynamically set message for twitter button?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I built a simple mapping tool that lets users explore local child care centers, associated information, an aggregate data (like city wards, child population density, and house hold income).  When someone finds something interesting, I want to help them post a tweet like:

> Look, the north end only has in-home child care, even the wealthy parts: http://t.co/KCfK2SVbIU #myMapApp

My map updates the url's hash value as the user browses around - users can then send that link to friends. Twitter's [hashtag button](https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons) would serve my purpose, but it loads up an iframe as soon as the page loads.

How can I keep the url for the twitter button up to date?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think this may work.

1. don't include twitter button at page load
2. provide a form for the user to compose their tweet in
3. on submit, write the iframe to the page with user tweet & url like this person did: [Load Tweet Button with jQuery into Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731888/load-tweet-button-with-jquery-into-container)
4. use a mask to get a nice iframe fade-in like this post does: [JQuery, fade in youtube iframe embed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865904/jquery-fade-in-youtube-iframe-embed)